# Can not GET and POST data to MongoDB from Flask in Docker

Tags: mongodb, docker, flask, docker-compose

I am using Flask and MongoDB inside docker. My Log shows everything fine but I can not GET and POST data, Even localhost:5000 does not work.

Here is my Docker-compose file

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  flask_example:
    build: .
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'
    links:
      - mongodb
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
```

Here in my Flask App

```
app.config['MONGO_DBNAME'] = 'restdb'
app.config['MONGO_URI'] = 'mongodb://mongodb:27017/restdb'
mongo = PyMongo(app)
```

I am getting the Log as follows :

> mongodb_1        | 2018-06-26T15:06:45.689+0000 I CONTROL 
>   [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1 port=27017 dbpath=/ data/db
>   64-bit host=64a180c6c04e mongodb_1        |
>   2018-06-26T15:06:45.689+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version
>   v3.6.5 mongodb_1        | 2018-06-26T15:06:45.689+0000 I CONTROL 
>   [initandlisten] git version: a20ecd3e3a174162052ff99913bc2ca 9a839d618
>   mongodb_1        | 2018-06-26T15:06:45.689+0000 I CONTROL 
>   [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016 mongodb_1 
>   | 2018-06-26T15:06:45.689+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator:
>   tcmalloc mongodb_1        | 2018-06-26T15:06:45.689+0000 I CONTROL 
>   [initandlisten] modules: none mongodb_1        |
>   2018-06-26T15:06:45.689+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build
>   environment: mongodb_1        | 2018-06-26T15:06:45.689+0000 I CONTROL
>   [initandlisten]     distmod: debian81 mongodb_1        |
>   2018-06-26T15:06:45.689+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch:
>   x86_64 mongodb_1        | 2018-06-26T15:06:45.689+0000 I CONTROL 
>   [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64 mongodb_1        |
>   2018-06-26T15:06:45.689+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {
>   net: { bindIpAll: true } } mongodb_1        |
>   2018-06-26T15:06:45.690+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] mongodb_1
>   | 2018-06-26T15:06:45.690+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING:
>   Using the XFS filesystem is stro ngly recommended with the WiredTiger
>   storage engine mongodb_1        | 2018-06-26T15:06:45.690+0000 I
>   STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/co
>   re/prodnotes-filesystem mongodb_1        |
>   2018-06-26T15:06:45.690+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten]
>   wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=47
>   8M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),cache_cursors=false,log
>   =(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=
>   0),verbose=(recovery_progress), mongodb_1        |
>   2018-06-26T15:06:46.604+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger
>   message [1530025606:604056][1:0x7 f9e1d704a00], txn-recover: Set
>   global recovery timestamp: 0 mongodb_1        |
>   2018-06-26T15:06:46.662+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] mongodb_1
>   | 2018-06-26T15:06:46.662+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING:
>   Access control is not enabled fo r the database. mongodb_1        |
>   2018-06-26T15:06:46.662+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **
>   Read and write access to data an d configuration is unrestricted.
>   mongodb_1        | 2018-06-26T15:06:46.662+0000 I CONTROL 
>   [initandlisten] mongodb_1        | 2018-06-26T15:06:46.663+0000 I
>   STORAGE  [initandlisten] createCollection: admin.system.version with
>   provided UUID: cdebc7d3-958e-43db-b517-bcfdc59e92ce mongodb_1        |
>   2018-06-26T15:06:46.692+0000 I COMMAND  [initandlisten] setting
>   featureCompatibilityVersion to 3.6 mongodb_1        |
>   2018-06-26T15:06:46.696+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten]
>   createCollection: local.startup_log with gen erated UUID:
>   5b6bb532-fde4-4156-bee9-e4bfa0ae55b7 mongodb_1        |
>   2018-06-26T15:06:46.731+0000 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing
>   full-time diagnostic data captu re with directory
>   '/data/db/diagnostic.data' mongodb_1        |
>   2018-06-26T15:06:46.731+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for
>   connections on port 27017 mongodb_1        |
>   2018-06-26T15:06:47.028+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted
>   from 172.28.0.3:46594 #1 (1 c onnection now open) flask_example_1  | 
>   * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading) flask_example_1  |  * Environment: production flask_example_1  |    WARNING: Do not use the
>   development server in a production environment. mongodb_1        |
>   2018-06-26T15:06:47.030+0000 I NETWORK  [conn1] received client
>   metadata from 172.28.0.3:46594 conn1 : { driver: { name: "PyMongo",
>   version: "3.6.1" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Linux", architecture:
>   "x86_64", version:  "4.9.87-linuxkit-aufs" }, platform: "CPython
>   3.6.5.final.0" } flask_example_1  |    Use a production WSGI server instead. flask_example_1  |  * Debug mode: on flask_example_1  |  *
>   Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
>   flask_example_1  |  * Restarting with stat mongodb_1        |
>   2018-06-26T15:06:47.283+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted
>   from 172.28.0.3:46596 #2 (2 c onnections now open) mongodb_1        |
>   2018-06-26T15:06:47.285+0000 I NETWORK  [conn2] received client
>   metadata from 172.28.0.3:46596 conn2 : { driver: { name: "PyMongo",
>   version: "3.6.1" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Linux", architecture:
>   "x86_64", version:  "4.9.87-linuxkit-aufs" }, platform: "CPython
>   3.6.5.final.0" } flask_example_1  |  * Debugger is active! flask_example_1  |  * Debugger PIN: 174-151-610

Answer (score 1):

Solved it

In production / docker it has to be as follows

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',debug=True)
```

therefore no `localhost:5000`, rather `0.0.0.0:5000`

Answer (score 0):

What I see here is Flask and mongo served on separate containers. 
I think you should fix the links section with hostname mapping:

```
links:
  - mongodb:mongodb
```